# Copy only a few rows

Tags: vb.net, excel

I need some help regarding MS Excel macro. I have 1,000+ rows, but I need only to copy a few to another worksheet. Columns are already sorted ascending to descending order. In short,  macro will only copy few rows, if cell "M26" have a value of = 6 then the macro will only copy 6 rows to another worksheet.

```
  x = 2
     Do While Cells(x, 1) <> ""
     If Cells(x, 3) = "Africa" Then
        Worksheets("srcSheets").Rows(x).Copy
        Worksheets("destSheet").Activate
        erow = Worksheets("destSheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("destSheet").Rows(erow)
     End If
         Worksheets("srcSheets").Activate
         x = x + 1
     Loop
```

Comment: You can also use a filter and copy the rows you need to another sheet. And some 1000 rows isn't really that much :)

Comment: Hi jerry, i already use filter and copy from another worksheet. The problem is I can't control how many rows should be copy in a worksheet.

Comment: Why not? When you select rows, there's a 'count' in the status bar and you can easily count the number of cells in one column and once you got the required number, select all the other columns without changing the number of rows and copy/paste. If you still want a macro, then you are expected to show what you have so far.

Comment: Jerry look for post update. Quite new in Macro

Answer (score 0):

This will copy rows 2 through x from sheet1 to sheet2 where x is the number in sheet2 A1. You may need to add some error handling though. Edit it to fit your needs.

```
Sub copyrows()

Dim x As Integer

x = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A1").Value

Worksheets("sheet1").Rows("2:" & x).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("sheet2").Rows(1)

End Sub
```